# Как сформировать ссылку на получение перевода криптовалюты Ton

Tags: api, transaction, blockchain, ton

Можно ли и как сформировать ссылку (возможно есть в api блокчейна Ton), которую я могу отправить кому-либо, получатель ссылки, перейдя по ней, получает установленную сумму монет с моего кошелька. В @wallet телеграм есть похожий сервис, когда контакту можнл отравить чек, активировав который, контакт получает перевод. Вот нужно что-то похожее.

Comment: как бы к программированию вообще непонятно каким боком этот вопрос относится.

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Есть бот в телеграм, который платит кешбек клиентам в криптовплюте тон. Нужно переделать код, чтобы бот не напрямую перечислял, а отправлял ссылку, например в виде qr кода. Клиент, когда ему удобно, переходил бы по ссылке и получал кешбек. Понимаю, что это сфера скорее всего Смарт-контрактов, но может есть более простые способы…